# Heroku App on deployment gets a H10 & 503 error

Tags: node.js, heroku

So on deploying my app to Heroku, it has started crashing. Unfortunately the log doesn't help as there is no detail.

1. I have tried restarting the app & it doesn't help.
2. The env variables are entered
3. The builpack is set to heroku-nodejs

The above 3 are what I found on web. Thanks for all the help.

Here is the log from Heroku

```
2020-07-17T12:07:45.791581+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-07-17T12:07:45.791685+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-07-17T12_07_45_784Z-debug.log
2020-07-17T12:07:45.848851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-07-17T12:07:45.894326+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-07-17T12:07:47.635979+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=marketool.herokuapp.com request_id=6af06835-645b-4427-b82d-1e77c46a3e98 fwd="42.106.46.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-07-17T12:07:49.538407+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=marketool.herokuapp.com request_id=48ff25a3-5b78-4ca6-80a0-d4d9bd170bf2 fwd="42.106.46.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this.

I had a wrong path for one of dependencies. Rectifying the right path is all that was needed.